# Db2 Performance issue in Azure. Hibernate with DB2

Tags: hibernate, db2

My application is having big query. when I am executing the query it is fast in db2 editor(squirrel ). But through application, it is very slow. it is taking 3 mins to execute that query.

select * from CPP.ItemSearchField itemsearch0_ left outer join CPP.Item item1_ on itemsearch0_.id=item1_.id left outer join CPP.Category category2_ on item1_.category_id=category2_.id left outer join CPP.SecurityGroup securitygr3_ on category2_.securityGroupId=securitygr3_.id left outer join CPP.SecurityGroup securitygr4_ on securitygr3_.parentId=securitygr4_.id left outer join CPP.ItemClassifier itemclassi5_ on item1_.itemClassifier_id=itemclassi5_.id left outer join CPP.Person person6_ on itemclassi5_.owner_id=person6_.id left outer join CPP.Account account7_ on person6_.id=account7_.id left outer join CPP.Person person8_ on account7_.id=person8_.id left outer join CPP.ItemClassifier itemclassi9_ on itemclassi5_.parentId=itemclassi9_.id left outer join CPP.ItemGroup itemgroup10_ on item1_.ItemGroupFK=itemgroup10_.id left outer join CPP.ReportingPeriod reportingp11_ on item1_.reportingPeriod_id=reportingp11_.id left outer join CPP.ReportingPeriodType reportingp12_ on reportingp11_.reportingPeriodTypeId=reportingp12_.id left outer join CPP.Attachment attachment13_ on item1_.id=attachment13_.itemFk where itemsearch0_.id=?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Provide details, so that someone without any knowledge of your query and project can understand the questions. For performance issues, provide the access plan. What is "db2 editor"? What kind of app? The same query and the same data?

Comment: You edited the question, but did not add any table definitions, info about indexes, or any access plan. Please add. Else your question cannot be answered and gets closed.